# JsonCpp do not protect from uint64 overflow and have weird behavior

Tags: c++, integer-overflow, jsoncpp

I am playing around with JsonCpp and have noticed weird behavior when getting to the end of uint64 range.

Numbers in range works properly.
Numbers above range but between `[2**64,2**64+2**11]` return 0.
Numbers above `2**64+2**11` throws an exception.

Is that expected? Can I configure JsonCpp to do those validations for me?

Thanks in advance!

Below is a code snippet that demonstrate the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/reader.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/value.h>


int main() {
    //std::string uint64Str = "1234"; // any number in range [0, 2**64-1] works correctly (prints uint64Str)
    //std::string uint64Str = "18446744073709551615"; // any number in range [0, 2**64-1] works correctly, including 2**64-1 (prints uint64Str)
    //std::string uint64Str = "18446744073709551616"; //max uint64 + 1 print 0
    //std::string uint64Str = "18446744073709551617"; //max uint64 + 2 print 0
    // ...
    //std::string uint64Str = "18446744073709553663"; //max uint64 + 2048 print 0
    //std::string uint64Str = "18446744073709553664"; //max uint64 + 2049 print 0
    std::string uint64Str = "18446744073709553665"; //max uint64 + 2050 (or more) throws instance of 'Json::LogicError' what():  double out of UInt64 range
    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader;
    bool parsingResult = reader.parse("{\"key\":"+uint64Str+"}", root);
        std::cout<<root["key"].asUInt64()<<std::endl;
    
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: unsigned integers do not overflow. They wrap around. What is "weird" about the behavior you see?

Comment: what is the value of `parsingResult`? Does the returned value perhaps indicate sucess/failure of the parsing?

Comment: parsingResult is true in all cases it does not throws an exception

Comment: @DannyCohen No, the exception comes when you try to squeeze the too large value into an `uint64_t` by calling `asUInt64()`

Comment: There are no ints or uints in JSON. There are only numbers, and they are unlimited in range and precision. So parsing is not supposed to fail. According to the source of jsoncpp, it is supposed to parse and internally store numbers greater than max uint64 value as double (or so is its intent). Then asUInt64 is supposed to raise an exception for such numbers. It looks like a bug in asUInt64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [TedLyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo) for the guidance.

After his answer and additional research.
Numbers that are bigger than max are stored in a real (double).

And then this code runs:

```
case realValue:
      JSON_ASSERT_MESSAGE(InRange(value_.real_, 0, maxUInt64),
                          "double out of UInt64 range");
      return UInt64( value_.real_ );
```

I would expect the function `InRange` to fail on numbers out of range.
However its implementation is:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
static inline bool InRange(double d, T min, U max) {
  // The casts can lose precision, but we are looking only for
  // an approximate range. Might fail on edge cases though. ~cdunn
  return d >= static_cast<double>(min) && d <= static_cast<double>(max);
}
```

It converts max to double and it rounds max up (to `2**64+2`) and if d is between `max<uint64> to 2**62+2**11` is is also rounded (to `2**64+2`).
So it thinks it is in range.
When converting d to uint64_t you get max+1 which is 0.

The function `InRange` do mention that is in not exact... yet, I consider that to be a bug in the library.

The solution that I am going to use is:

```
uint64_t getUint64(const Json::Value& shouldBeUInt64) {
    uint64_t res = shouldBeUInt64.asUInt64();
    if (res == 0 and shouldBeUInt64.asDouble()>0){
        throw Json::LogicError("double out of UInt64 range");
    }
    return res;
}
```

Update (25 Nov 2023):
See suggested fix here:
https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/pull/1519

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the very large number is stored as a *real* (it doesn't fit in an `uint64_t`). You need to read it as a *real* too:

```cpp
std::cout << root["key"].asDouble() << std::endl;
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The actual exception comes from a `switch` inside `Value::UInt64 Value::asUInt64() const` in which a `realValue` is checked if it can fit in the requested range:

```cpp
case realValue:
      JSON_ASSERT_MESSAGE(InRange(value_.real_, 0, maxUInt64),
                          "double out of UInt64 range");
      return UInt64( value_.real_ );
```

Comment: That is Javascript convention, but I don't think it is applied to C++

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux What is a javascript convention? I know almost nothing about javascript so I can't tell.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have integers, I believe. Integers are doubles with 53bits of mantissa used

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I still don't understand what in my answer that is using javascript conventions? In C++ there are integers and an `uint64_t`  can only hold a limited range of values. OPs value is not one of them and the value is stored as a real type internally. Trying to read it out as an `uint64_t` causes the exception, because it simply doesn't fit in an `uint64_t`.

Comment: To me it looks like storing integers as real in JsonCPP  came from the wish to be compatible with Javascript side of thing, where there is no "integer". Anyway, just a thought.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux It may very well store smaller integers as plain integers and only use real types when a value becomes too large. I didn't look that deep into the JsonCPP code right now.

Comment: I agree with your answer. I added print of root["key"].type() and actually saw that it is converted to real once I pass max<uint64_t>.
But why is zero returned? I would expect that the number will be rounded down to max<uint64_t>.

Comment: @DannyCohen Zero is surprising. I get `1.84467e+19` when I call `asDouble()`. Rounding down could cause real problems. A `double` can hold numbers that are extremely large compared to what `uint64_t` can hold so the rounding could make rockets crash etc :-) I think an exception is prefered in case the number doesn't fit the type.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I agree, I would like to get an expection in both cases.
Do you know how can I do that?
How can I check if the number is in range and not really zero?

Comment: @DannyCohen One way would be to check if `asDouble() < 0 or asDouble() > std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max()` - or just try with `asUInt64()` and catch the exception.

Comment: asUInt64() returns 0 for `[2**64,2**64+2**10]`, so that will not work.
Checking if `asDouble() > std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max()` is possible, I will try a more exact and compact solution.

Comment: @DannyCohen One possible way if you are not interested in values below `0` and above the limit for `uint64_t` could be to `clamp` the result: `static_cast<std::uint64_t>(std::clamp(0., static_cast<double>(std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max()), asDouble()))` - there could be potential problems in that too though. Not 100% sure.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I would like to get in exception when passing this range. I think I will use you previous suggestion.
Thank you!

Comment: @DannyCohen I think you should submit a bug report to JsonCPP. It is totally unreasonable to return 0 for these numbers.